# Area calculation in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, area, utm, spain

I'm using PostgreSQL 14.1 with PostGIS 3.1.

I've got a UTM 10x10 km grid `malla`, set in EPSG 25830, that covers all Spanish territories:

[image]

I have run the following code (just to check that everything is OK)

```
select utmcode, cast(st_area(m.geom)/10000 as integer) ha
from malla m;
```

but it returns values over 10,000 ha, meaning that the calculation is not accurate. I guess it's a matter of the projection, since the westernmost grids have the largest deviances, but I'm not sure as how to proceed. How could I overcome the problem?

Comment: It looks like the 10 kmx10km grid is originally created separately for each UTM zone but you calculate the areas when all data are projected to EPSG:25830. When you look at the data, are the areas of the most western and eastern cells systematically larger than for the cells at the middle?

Comment: @user30184 Yes, they were probably created separately, as you guess. Do you think that I should split them back and make any calculations separately or would there be a solution for working with all of them together?

Comment: Because you have data in PostGIS it might be best to use "geography" when computing areas and distances.

Comment: @user30184 Is it feasible to do so with a UTM grid?

Comment: Well, the UTM grid shells won't be exactly 10000 hectares if calculated as geographies. Split by UTM zones and re-projecting cells of each slice into their native zone could be an option but it really depends on what is your goal.